# Core Data concurrency type not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

As per Apple I create my core data stack in the App Delegate and then pass the managedObjectContext to my first controller and then from there to the second and so on.

I'm trying to do some work in a background thread and want to use a PrivateConcurrency type but I get the error that the parent must be Main or Private.

In app delegate I create the context

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

then I pass it to my first controller

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
Paperwoven_LoadingViewController *firstController = (Paperwoven_LoadingViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
[firstController setManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
NSLog(@"concurrency type is %@", [self managedObjectContext]);
NSLog(@"concurrency type is %u",firstController.managedObjectContext.concurrencyType);
```

I can see that when I log out the concurrency type from self I get 2 which is Main. But when I check the context I just sent to the firstcontroller I get 0. Why is it not passing correctly?

**EDIT**

Additionally I can get the managedObjectContext via `AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` and I can see the concurrency type is MAIN but if in the next line I do `self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext` then check the concurrency type on self.managedObjectContext it is 0. Looks like assigning it from App delegate to a controller loses concurrency type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm an idiot, sort of. Another developer put the same core data stack methods in the Base controller that all controllers have. What occurred is I was able to set a controllers context but then the base controller would create its own context and overwrite the one passed in. Removing this garbage code fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the most likely explanation is that `firstController` is nil. You get it using this line:

```
Paperwoven_LoadingViewController *firstController = (Paperwoven_LoadingViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
```

But if `topViewController` is nil then `firstViewController` is nil. In the following lines:

```
[firstController setManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
NSLog(@"concurrency type is %@", [self managedObjectContext]);
NSLog(@"concurrency type is %u",firstController.managedObjectContext.concurrencyType);
```

Sending a message to nil is not an error in Objective-C, so the first line is a no-op. In the last line above, you're printing `nil.managedObjectContext.concurrencyType`, which will be 0.

This doesn't look like a Core Data problem-- more like a problem getting your view controllers configured.

Comment: If I log out [navigationController.topViewController class] I get the correct class. Whouldn't that be nil or empty if the controller was nil?

Comment: Thanks Tom for the advice. Best place to start is making sure your object is not nil and is what you expect it to be. In the end it was not knowing that the original developer setup the core data stack in the base controller even though they weren't using core data at the time. So those conflicted with my stack